# Pass few elements to methods

Tags: c#, refactoring

I've few methods which acept collections of fixed size (e.g. 2, 3, 5). And I can't decide which way is better:

```
public void Foo(IEnumerable<Object> objects)
{
    if(objects.Count() != 3)
    {
        throw new Exception()
    }
    // actions
}

public void Foo(Object objectA, Object objectB, Object objectC)
{
    // actions
}
```

Is there any ultimate  +\- of each option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second is much better in my view:

- It's obvious from the signature that it's expecting 3 values
- Failures are flagged at compile time instead of execution time

Comment: although the first method could be more flexible

Comment: @lordkain the number of members of the collection required makes it LESS flexible, since you'll incur an exception that isn't highlighted when invoking the method.  It's more dangerous and it's misleading, since the "flexibility" is a misnomer

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific number of members that are required, use your second option.  It is confusing to the consumer of your method if a collection is allowed but then an exception is thrown at run time.  This may or may not be caught if proper testing is not utilized and it is misleading.  Always design for the person who will consume your code, never assuming that you will always be the one to maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Object object1;
    public Object object2;
    public Object object3;

    // add a constructor if you want
}

...

public void Foo(Bar b)
{
      // actions
}
```